# Simple mysql join takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have a query that takes it too long to execute (about 5 mins):

```
SELECT
    itc_route.adep,
    itc_route.aircraft_id,
    Airport.IATA
FROM
    itc_route
LEFT JOIN airports_copy AS Airport ON itc_route.adep = Airport.icao
WHERE
    itc_route.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01'
AND '2015-12-01'
```

This part takes me 0.180s to execute

```
SELECT * FROM airports_copy
```

And this one takes me 0.560s

```
SELECT * FROM itc_route WHERE itc_route.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-12-01'
```

But when I do join them - it takes just a way too long!

So here my indexes for itc_route table:[image: itc_route indexes]

Here is my airports_copy indexes: [image: airports_copy indexes]

And here is an explain statement:[image: explain statement]

Any idea?

Comment: You need all the properties? What mysql db engine ' re using

Comment: @EnriqueQuero It's myISAM

Comment: what are the data types of the two columns itc_route.adep and Airport.icao? Maybe they are different types and the database performs an implicit typecast for every dataset?

Comment: @Olli Both of them are varchar

Comment: shoot... too bad... is the database using your date index when you simply use this query: SELECT * FROM itc_route WHERE itc_route.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-12-01'

Comment: can you please post the table structures as well?

Comment: @Olli It is not using index on date. I added force index and now it is reduced to 200'000 rows, but it is still takes too long to execute.
And I'm afraid I can't share a full structure for those tables, sry :(

Comment: An OUTER JOIN seems an odd choice, as it seems unlikely that there would be a row for which there was no IATA.

Answer (score 1):

If more than, say, 20% of the rows are in that date range, then the optimizer will decide it is faster to simply do a table scan.  Note: This is not necessarily the slow part of the task.

After getting those rows, then it has to look up in the other table.  This *may* be the slow part.

You are using MyISAM.  (You should consider changing to InnoDB.)  If `key_buffer_size` is too small, there may be thrashing going on in that cache.  That setting should be about 20% of *available* RAM.

It looks like you have a "prefix" index?  `Name(8)`.  Don't do that; it hurts performance.

`Airport` needs a composite index:  `INDEX(icao, IATA)`.

The `EXPLAIN` and the table definitions do not agree.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is clearer and more complete than the images you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use innodb If you are not using that.
Create a multi column index on the (icao,IATA) in airports_copy with which you can take advantage of covering index.
Now try the following query. If not works fine then post your explain here.

```
  SELECT
    itc_route.adep,
    itc_route.aircraft_id,
    intr.IATA
FROM
    itc_route
left JOIN 
(
select IATA,icao from airports_copy
) as intr
on intr.icao =itc_route.adep

WHERE
    itc_route.date between '2014-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
```